# Google StorageTransfer job from S3 to GCS failed due to The caller does not have permission

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-client

I tried to transfer a file from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud Storage using API. I did successfully on the GCP console but when I'm writing a Python script using a service account credential, I got `HttpError 403 when requesting https://storagetransfer.googleapis.com/v1/transferJobs?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission`

Also, My service account is already a Storage Object Admin.

The script I'm using

```
import google.auth
import google_auth_httplib2
import google.oauth2.service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


_DEFAULT_SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',)

credentials = (
                    google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                        key_path, scopes=_DEFAULT_SCOPES)
                )

http = httplib2.Http()
http_authorized = google_auth_httplib2.AuthorizedHttp(
            credentials, http=http)

conn = build('storagetransfer', 'v1', http=http_authorized, cache_discovery=False)
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

project_id='projectid'
transfer_spec = {
    'awsS3DataSource': {
        'bucketName': 's3_bucket',
        'awsAccessKey': {
            'accessKeyId': 'key',
            'secretAccessKey': 'secret',
        }
    },
    'gcsDataSink': {
        'bucketName': 'bucket',
    },
    'objectConditions': {'includePrefixes': ['PREFIX']},
    'transferOptions': {'overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink': True},
}

transfer_job = {
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'projectId': project_id,
            'transferSpec': transfer_spec,
            'schedule': {
                'scheduleStartDate': {
                    'day': now.day,
                    'month': now.month,
                    'year': now.year,
                },
                'scheduleEndDate': {
                    'day': now.day,
                    'month': now.month,
                    'year': now.year,
                }
            }
        }

job = conn.transferJobs().create(body=transfer_job).execute()
```

Does anyone know what's missing?

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/create

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, It hasn’t solved yet

Comment: Having the same issue -- did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#before_you_start) you need to assign one of the following permission owner/editor/storagetransfer.admin/storagetransfer.user. There is also a python scripting example might be helpful to transfer data from S3 to GCS.